# Change search flow from left-right;top-bottom, to top-bottom;left-right

Tags: excel, vba

I want it to start searching the first column from top to bottom, then the second and so on.

In the "for each" part I want to Change the flow

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For j = 2 To 2
        For i = 21 To 21

            If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
                Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value - 1
                Cells(i, j).Offset(0, -1).Select
            End If

            'that is the Matrix I want to Change the search flow in'
            For Each cell In Range("a2:aap15")

                If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
                    If cell.Value = "" Then

                        cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
                        Exit For

                    End If
                End If

            Next    
        Next    
    Next

End Sub
```

I have to write this sentence, because stackoverlow doesn't let me post until it thinks I don't have mostly code anymore.

New Suggestion (still the same Problem):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'NEW'
Dim cell As Range, column As Range

For j = 2 To 2
For i = 21 To 21

If Cells(i - 1, j).Value = 0 Then
If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
Cells(i, j).Value = Cells(i, j).Value - 1
Cells(i, j).Offset(0, -1).Select
End If
End If


'NEW'
For Each column In Range("a2:aap15").Columns
    For Each cell In column.Cells


If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
If cell.Value = "" Then

cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value

Exit For

End If
End If

Next
Next   
Next
next

End Sub
```

[how it shold be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9S4F.png)

[how it is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYqeU.png)

Comment: Do you actually have anything at all (even a single value) in the first row? .AutoFilter is screwing up with your sample data due to a blank first row.

Comment: No, my first row is empty. why?

Comment: You want to work with `a2:aap15` but .AutoFilter requires a 'header' row and row 1 is blank. A single value in any cell in row 1 would fix that.

Comment: I put in a value, is there anything else I have to Change. Cause it didn't matter

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by iterating over the cells of the columns of your range.

---

```
Dim cell As Range, column As Range

For Each column In Range("a2:aap15").Columns
    For Each cell In column.Cells

        If cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
            If cell.Value = "" Then

                cell.Value = ActiveCell.Value
                Exit For

            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: your correction is still leading to the same flow, if using my whole code.

Comment: I don't see how.  Using a `For Each` loop on a range results in rows being iterated before column.  My answer iterates over columns and than rows.

Comment: Well, I don't see how either.

Comment: Can you post a before and after picture?

Comment: No, an screenshot of the spreadsheet before the code is ran and one of the expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

The following relies on the [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844.aspx). .AutoFilter requires a 'header' row that is not included in processing but row 1 cannot be completely blank.

```
Option Explicit

Sub firstBlankYellows()
    Dim c As Long, str As String

    str = "Task 1"
    With Worksheets("Sheet4")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:AP15")
            For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
                With .Columns(c)
                    .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 255, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
                    With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                        If Not Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
                                         .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)) Is Nothing Then
                            Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), _
                                      .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks))(1) = str
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End With
                    .AutoFilter
                End With
            Next c
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: If I enter that codee it says "Not valid within a procedure"

Comment: I've made a modification above.